# Ubuntu Creates New Boot entry in Uefi manager after update command

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Asus gl552vw laptop in which i install ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows during normal operation boot grub is shown and ubuntu entry is first. But after update command from uubuntu, booting is stuck at asus log . When you press esc key and power on a new ubuntu boot entry is seen along with Windows and older ubuntu The new one seems corrupted and is the first boot option there system not boot. But older ubuntu option is working. I deleted the corrupted entry and now booting up. But why new boot entry is created after update command? How can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: solve aayo problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a package update, like `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? If so, then chances are you pulled down a GRUB (boot loader) or Shim (pre-bootloader) update that caused it to be re-installed. This could easily cause a new boot entry to be created, and if that process went badly, you'd see the results you did. As to why it might go wrong, several possibilities occur to me:

- **Corrupted NVRAM** -- EFI computers are prone to corruption of their NVRAM, and when this happens, all sorts of bad things can happen, including improperly-created new boot entries. If you think your NVRAM is corrupted, you may be able to clear the problem by using a firmware option to reset all settings to their defaults; however, this will likely wipe not just the boot order list, but all references to your boot loaders, which will then require repair.
- **A new bug in Ubuntu** -- Creation of boot entries relies on several tools, including GRUB's post-installation scripts, the `efibootmgr` utility, and the Linux kernel. A new bug in any of these tools might result in bogus new entries being created. If you think this is a new Ubuntu bug, you might try [reporting it;](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) however, to be useful, such a bug report will need a lot more detail than you've provided here, such as the *exact* and *repeatable* conditions under which a problem occurs.
- **EFI bugs** -- The firmware itself might have a bug that created a duplicate entry, but bungled the process.
- **Windows bugs** -- Similarly, if you booted into Windows at some point, it could be that something went wrong in Windows.
- **User error** -- If you were using `efibootmgr` (or an equivalent tool in Windows or the firmware) for some reason, you might have created the bogus entry yourself.

Some of these, particularly late in the list, seem very unlikely to me; however, I can't rule them out entirely. My guess is that you're looking at one of the first two possibilities.